# Permission Denied for media files at AWS S3 with Heroku and Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

In order to let the user upgrade some images in my `django` project I've decided to use AWS S3 buckets.

I've followed a couple of tutorials and everything seems to look fine with my media storage backend because I can see the updated files on my bucket.

The problem is that the images aren't been served in the site. When I try to open it a simple XML appears showing an "Access Denied" error:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>33BFF888CD1CA014</RequestId>
    <HostId>UEeWZpvsQzOoIvq9uSz7Xqo7KAFhHmsPsXxEGwxaDW6V1mM2B0EccXSMXj0NXCnbi+VlwlL9d00=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Some infos that might be useful:

1. My IAM user is in a group with a AmazonS3FullAccess policy;
2. I've tried to enable public access to my bucket and it didn't work;
3. My bucket is in the us-east-2 region;
4. I updated the bucket CORS configuration according to [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python#s3-setup) heroku tutorial.

Any idea on what could be causing this error?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are these images supposed to be public - accessible through browser? If yes, then what is your bucket policy?

Comment: Yes, the images are supposed to be public. I haven't set any policy to my bucket. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, all buckets and objects are private. To enable public access to your images you have to set **bucket policy** to enable that:

- [Granting Read-Only Permission to an Anonymous User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2)

For example:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can further limit the policy to be accessible from your website using [aws:Referer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4) condition. But please note that the use of `aws:Referer` is not a bullet proof solution to limit access to bucket only from your domain and it could be rather easily circumvent.

You also have to disable block [public access settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html).

If you don't want to make your bucket public, you can use CloudFront in front of your bucket to provide public access to images:

- [Amazon S3 + Amazon CloudFront: A Match Made in the Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/)

Comment: For now I'll go with public access. I didn't know that I need to create a policy for the bucket as well (I tought only disabling block public access settings would do the trick). Thanks a lot!